# Expand env variables in String

Tags: java, string, environment-variables

Is there some java utility, which will expand ~ and env. variables in a string?

Like "~/bin;${MY_PATH}" -> "/home/john/bin;/dev/null"

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you want to do String interpolation with environment variables and expand home directories. I don't know of an easy way to do the latter, but if you use Spring to do your set-up you can use it's [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to replace placeholders in strings.

By default, environment variables are included in the set of placeholder replacements.

UPDATE: As this is from the user, you can still make use of Spring helper classes:

```
String stringToBeInterpolated = ....;
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
PropertyPlaceholderHelper helper = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper("${","}");
String interpolatedValue = helper.replacePlaceholders(stringToBeInterpolated , properties);
```

This doesn't help with the ~, but at that point I'd assume you can do a fairly simple string replace operation.

Comment: No, it is a user file content, it is not my spring bean.

Comment: Updated to show how you can make use of the same underlying Spring code on user content.

Comment: Wondering how Properties.getProperty gets implemented. Pretty sure it does not use PropertyPlaceholderHelper.

Comment: Note that `org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper` is a Spring class, which is then a prerequisite here.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the full path for the `bin` folder and use `System.getProperty("EVN_PROP_HERE")`

Comment: No, I have a String with some path, including env vars and "~". 
Consider "Here may be some path: ~/${PATH}". I do not want parse it, extract {PATH}, compute it and build the string again. I want some utility which will get "Here may be some path: ~/${PATH}" and return "Here may be some path: /home/john/bin".