# Interpolating environment variables in string

Tags: java, environment-variables, string-interpolation

I need to expand environment variables in a string. For example, when parsing a config file, I want to be able to read this...

`statsFile=${APP_LOG_DIR}/app.stats`

And get a value of "/logs/myapp/app.stats", where the environment variable APP_LOG_DIR = "/logs/myapp".

This seems like a very common need, and things like the Logback framework do this for their own config files, but I have not found a canonical way of doing this for my own config files.

Notes:

1. This is *not* a duplicate of the many "variable interpolation in java strings" questions. I need to interpolate *environment* variables in the specific format ${ENV_VAR}.
2. The same question was asked here, [Expand env variables in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593247/expand-env-variables-in-string), but the answer requires the Spring framework, and I don't want to pull in this huge dependency just to do this one simple task.
3. Other languages, like go, have a simple built-in function for this: [Interpolate a string with bash-like environment variables references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915429/interpolate-a-string-with-bash-like-environment-variables-references). I am looking for something similar in java.

Comment: The variable APP_LOG_DIR is an environment variable or a property within your configuration file?

Comment: APP_LOG_DIR is an environment variable that I want to reference in my config file with the use of the ${APP_LOG_DIR} syntax.

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752817/expand-environment-variables-in-text

Comment: @radulfr, that looks similar to what I need. For such a common requirement, I was thinking there would be a solution that didn't require writing my own function, but this may work if I can't find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Thanks to clues from @radulfr's link in the comments above to [Expand environment variables in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752817/expand-environment-variables-in-text), I found a pretty clean solution, using StrSubstitutor, here: https://dkbalachandar.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/how-to-use-strsubstitutor/

To summarize:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrLookup;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor;

public class StrSubstitutorMain {

    private static final StrSubstitutor envPropertyResolver = new StrSubstitutor(new EnvLookUp());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sample = "LANG: ${LANG}";
        //LANG: en_US.UTF-8
        System.out.println(envPropertyResolver.replace(sample));

    }

    private static class EnvLookUp extends StrLookup {

        @Override
        public String lookup(String key) {
            String value = System.getenv(key);
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("key" + key + "is not found in the env variables");
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as of 2022, both `StrLookup` and `StrSubstitutor` are deprecated

so I update @sagebrush’s answer:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lookup.StringLookup;
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

public class StrSubstitutorMain {

    private static final StringSubstitutor envPropertyResolver = new StringSubstitutor(new EnvLookUp());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sample = "LANG: ${LANG}";
        //LANG: en_US.UTF-8
        System.out.println(envPropertyResolver.replace(sample));

    }

    private static class EnvLookUp implements StringLookup {

        @Override
        public String lookup(String key) {
            String value = System.getenv(key);
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("key" + key + "is not found in the env variables");
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.  For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and you could have a similar string template that avoids JavaScript injection attacks.